# Inequality with size of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Let $ k$ be an integer, $ k \geq 2$, and let $ p_{1},\ p_{2},\ \ldots,\ p_{k}$ be positive reals with $ p_{1}+p_2+\cdots+p_k= 1$. Suppose we have a collection $ \left(A_{1,1},\ A_{1,2},\ \ldots,\ A_{1,k}\right)$, $ \left(A_{2,1},\ A_{2,2},\ \ldots,\ A_{2,k}\right)$, $ \ldots$, $ \left(A_{m,1},\ A_{1,2},\ \ldots,\ A_{m,k}\right)$ of $ k$-tuples of finite sets satisfying the following two properties:

- (i) for every $ i$ and every $ j \neq j^{\prime}$, $ A_{i,j}\cap
     A_{i,j^{\prime}}=\emptyset$,
- (ii) for every $ i\neq i^{\prime}$ there exist $ j\neq j^{\prime}$
  for which $ A_{i,j} \cap A_{i^{\prime},j^{\prime}}\neq\emptyset$.

Prove that
$$ \sum_{b=1}^{m}{\prod_{a=1}^{k}{p_{a}^{|A_{\,b,\,a}|}}} \leq 1$$
This problem is from some exam for undergraduate students in our country. This was the hardest problem ever proposed there. Could someone help me solve it? I tried induction but failed in proving the base case for $m=1$. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Why not ? For $m=1$, the "worst case" is when all the $A$s are empty; in this case $|A_j| = 0$ and we have the product of $k$ times $1$, which is $1$. Then assume that we have all $|A_j| = 1$; in this case we have the product of $k$ **positive** real $p_i \le 1$; again the result is $\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you but how to extend this for general $m$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See taking examples and progressing intuitively is helpful, but I seek a rigorous solution. For long time I have taken examples and tried to find a pattern, but I can't rigorise it. So if you could give a complete proof, if you have one, then it would be very helpful. Thanks for all the helpful insights btw.

Comment: Haha well, I don't know also. Anyways, I can ensure you it is correct. It is indeed from an exam. Sadly the official solutions are rarely known, so I have not even a slightest idea about the solution meant to be. Anyways thanks for helping again.